# Is it possible to configure intellisense in VS 2015 so that when a local variable is generated it is initialized with the default value for its type?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I often use the Generate Local Variable feature of the VS 2015 intellisense. But the variables are generated uninitialised. In 99% of the case this is not what I want.

Is it possible to configure the intellisense to initialize the generated variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search around there have no such function or extension to implement your requirement, I shared this suggestion with the VS Product Team and please check this: [VS 2015>quick actions with light bulbs: please add the support to custom/modify the Generate Local Variable feature](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32068156-vs-2015-quick-actions-with-light-bulbs-please-add), you can vote it and the higher vote number can make the VS Product Team engineers to notice this suggestion.